# Silex 2.0 Redirection

Tags: silex

I'm a Silex newbie and I'd like to redirect the '/' url to the default language like '/en' for example. I do this :

```
$app->match('/', function(Application $app){

    return $app->redirect('/Silex/www/'.$app['locale_fallbacks'][0]);
});
```

Am I constrained to put the absolute url from the root of the server ? I'd like to put only `$app->redirect('$app['locale_fallbacks'][0]);`. And is it the right way to get the default language ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to give the host there. As in your `match()` you will pass a relative url. However it would probably be better not to make a new roundtrip to the browser and to forward the request internally or even rewrite it via `.htaccess`.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

$app->match('/', function () use ($app) {
    $subRequest = Request::create('/' . $app['locale_fallbacks'][0], 'GET');
    return $app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
});
```

Comment: Worth mention that the /Silex/www/ directory in URL should be omitted using a rewrite (Apache / nginx)